# Decent LAN/Internet games for Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, games

Since the decommission of Halo Demo for Mac, I have had no decent LAN/Internet games to play with my Mac.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

I like First Person Shooters and Third Person Shooters the best, if you can think of any of those. They must be free.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Questions should usually have one definitive answer, and software recommendation questions are generally only allowed if they are very specific. I'm closing this for now, but if you can edit it to make it a lot more specific feel free to flag and I'll reopen. Thanks.